# Inputting a list of files in a for loop corrupts special characters

Tags: loops, input-encodings

I have a `main.tex` beamer file and a list of files in a subfolder like:

```
subfolder/John1.tex
subfolder/John2.tex
subfolder/John3.tex
subfolder/Mike1.tex
subfolder/Mike2.tex
subfolder/Mike3.tex
subfolder/Mike4.tex
```

In my `main.tex`, I also have a for loop as follows:

```
\usepackage{pgffor}
\newcommand{\allByPerson}[3]{\foreach \c in {1,2,...,#3}{\input{#1/#2\c.tex}}}
```

So that

```
\input{subfolder/John1.tex}
\input{subfolder/John2.tex}
\input{subfolder/John3.tex}
```

should produce the same pdf as

```
\allByPerson{subfolder}{John}{3}
```

The problem is that although I have `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` loaded, the `\allByPerson` command produces corrupted **special characters (for example ş becomes 7s)**. On the other hand, when I `\input` them one by one, no such problem occurs.

Comment: What "special characters" are you referring to that appear in your filenames?  (I do not see any filenames with special characters)

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Sorry about the confusion, the characters I'm referring to are inside the tex files. For example subfolder/John1.tex contains characters like "ç ğ ı ö ş ü"

Comment: I would note this occurs only under `pdflatex`, but works OK under `xelatex` and `lualatex`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that this issue only affects `pdflatex`, which certainly leads one to believe the problem is encoding related.

We start with the following input file `./John1.tex` (as suggested by the OP in a comment):

```
ç ğ ı ö ş ü
```

Here is an MWE that successfully recreates the original problem, in that `\input` works as expected when applied directly to `John1.tex`, but when it is wrapped inside the macro `\allByPerson`, it garbles some characters of the input file.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\newcommand{\allByPerson}[3]{\foreach \c in {1,...,#3}{\input{#1/#2\c.tex}}}
\begin{document}
\input{./John1.tex}

\allByPerson{.}{John}{1}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The fact that the issue arises on those tokens with cedillas, which can be constructed in pdflatex by way of `\c`, and noting that the `pgffor` loop variable is also chosen as `\c` raises a red flag.

Let us just rename the loop variable from `\c` to `\z`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\newcommand{\allByPerson}[3]{\foreach \z in {1,...,#3}{\input{#1/#2\z.tex}}}
\begin{document}
\input{./John1.tex}

\allByPerson{.}{John}{1}
\end{document}
```

Just changing the `pgffor` loop variable from `\c` to `\z` fixes the problem.

[image]

**LESSON:** Do not use already defined macros as your loop variable in `pgffor` loops, especially if those macros are related to font encodings.

Comment: Wow, amazing. I would have never guessed that. Thank you for your valuable answer.